# Does Smite work while wild-shaped?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, paladin, wild-shape

Does Smite work in beast form? I have a plan for a half orc Paladin/Druid build, but I want to make sure this aspect of the build works before I play the character.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Divine Smite will work while Wild Shaped. Wild Shape allows you to use your class features:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if your new form is physically capable of doing so.

And Divine Smite works like this:

> Starting at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a
>   melee weapon attack, you can expend one paladin spell
>   slot to deal radiant damage to the target, in addition to
>   the weapon's damage.

Divine Smite requires a melee weapon attack. Every beast type creature that I can think of has at least one attack that is a melee weapon attack. For example, the Wolf:

> ***Bite.*** Melee Weapon Attack: +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target.
>   Hit: 7 (2d4 + 2) piercing damage. If the target is a creature,
>   it must succeed on a DC 11 Strength saving throw or be
>   knocked prone.

So you can use your Divine Smite with the melee weapon attacks provided by your Wild Shape form.

Comment: [Divine Smite also requires the attack to be made with a weapon.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/905513839617335296) Do "natural weapons" count as weapons? You should clarify that in your answer.

Comment: [Crawford answers a question here about Booming Blade](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/756175937536794625) and starts his answer "**As DM**, I'd allow a natural weapon (not a regular unarmed strike) to work with an effect like booming blade." So by RAW, I think neither Booming Blade nor Divine Smite works with a natural weapon.

Answer (score -7):

The rule says it applies when you make a "melee weapon attack," so unless your beast form is using a melee weapon, I would say "no."

Comment: All natural weapons for all beasts are melee weapon attacks. Even unarmed strikes are melee weapon attacks, since they're on the list of simple weapons. The only melee attack that isn't a melee weapon attack is melee spell attacks.

Comment: Not arguing, just trying to understand. What I'm finding is PHBp195 that talks about "monsters" making melee attacks when it strikes with horn, claw, etc. It does not refer to them as "melee weapon attacks" which I take to mean a melee attack with an actual weapon. Also says that some spells count as a melee attack, but again, no mention of "weapon." Do you have a section/page number I could refer to? Thanks!

Comment: Unarmed strikes are no longer melee weapon attacks as per errata: http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf

Comment: @xristofer with regards to monsters: that's just what that section of the PHB says. The Monster Manual and Appendix D in the PHB has actual stat blocks for monsters and they do class hooves, claws, etc. as melee *weapon* attacks.

Comment: Per the errata while unarmed strikes isn't a "melee weapon" insofar as you don't need to equip it, they are still melee weapon attacks. A melee weapon, by definition, is anything used to cause damage in a melee. So yes, an unarmed strike is still a strike with a melee weapon. Just like a wolf biting you is striking you with his teeth, another effective melee weapon.

Comment: I do not believe smiles would work with unarmed Monk attacks, Lino Frank Ciaralli, but that is a different discussion.