# Does the half orc's Savage Attacks trait work when wild shaped?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, racial-traits, half-orc

Does the half-orc's Savage Attacks trait work while Wild Shaped in beast form?

I have a plan for a half-orc Paladin/Druid build, but I want to make sure this aspect of the build works before I play the character.

Comment: Related: [Can a half-orc's Savage Attacks and a monk's unarmed strike work together?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88852/can-a-half-orcs-savage-attacks-and-a-monks-unarmed-strike-work-together), [Does Smite work while wild-shaped?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64099/does-smite-work-while-wild-shaped)

Comment: @V2Blast It looks like you have an answer to give to [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5761/15469).

Comment: @Miniman: Eh. The tag existed, I figured it was appropriate to include. I have no strong feelings one way or the other. I didn't realize there had been a discussion about this before. (Though the fact that this is a question about a half-orc racial trait in particular suggests it is specifically about half-orcs as well as about the druid's Wild Shape feature...)

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the Savage Attacks ability will work while Wild Shaped. Wild Shape allows you to use your racial features:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if your new form is physically capable of doing so.

Savage Attacks kicks in when you get a critical hit with a melee weapon attack:

> ***Savage Attacks.*** When you score a critical hit with
>   a melee weapon attack, you can roll one of the weapon's
>   damage dice one additional time and add it to the extra
>   damage of the critical hit.

Every beast type creature that I can think of has at least one attack that is a melee weapon attack. For example, the Wolf:

> ***Bite.*** Melee Weapon Attack: +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target.
>   Hit: 7 (2d4 + 2) piercing damage. If the target is a creature,
>   it must succeed on a DC 11 Strength saving throw or be
>   knocked prone.

So if you get a critical hit while Wild Shaped into a Wolf, it will deal 5d4 instead of 4d4.